# How can my friend and I play TF2 against bots?

Tags: team-fortress-2

How can I setup TF2 so that two players (myself and someone inexperienced with FPS) can both play in a map against bots, but not people.

I guess I need to hunt through the internet list trying to find servers that are populated and checking namelists to see if they look like bots.

The offline practice probably won't work as that looks like single player.

Any advice on how best to do this, or just tips to make finding a server on the internet list like this a bit easier would be greatly appreciated.

We're on the same LAN, so maybe there's a way of hosting a LAN game that both me & the other person can join?

Comment: I'm guessing hosting your own server is not an option.

Comment: not sure - I'll have to look into what the requirements are for hosting (specs etc.)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here is an instruction on how to create a server and put bots on it:

1. Make sure you have the port *27015* accessible for connections.
   <sup>How? Look [here](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/routerindex.htm).</sup>
2. Open the game console.
   <sup>How? *Options⇨Keyboard⇨Advanced...⇨Enable developer console.* Press <kbd>~</kbd> / <kbd>`</kbd> to open the console at any time.</sup>
3. <sup>[image: Optional]</sup> Type `sv_lan 0` if you want the game to be public, or `sv_lan 1` for LAN only.
   <sup>Public server is recommended</sup>
4. Type `map <mapname>`, replacing *<mapname>* with the name of the map you want to play.
   <sup>Or press the [+] to the right of *BROWSE SERVERS* in main menu instead.</sup>
5. <sup>[image: Optional]</sup> If the server is public and you don't want anyone to intrude, you can set a password:
   Type `sv_password <pass>`, replacing *<pass>* with some simple password.
   <sub>(e.g. `sv_password 1234`)</sub>
6. Set the bot difficulty: `tf_bot_difficulty <x>`, where *<x>* is from 0 (the easiest) to 3.
   <sup>(e.g. `tf_bot_difficulty 0`)</sup>
7. [Add bots](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Bots#AI_Bot_Commands): `tf_bot_add <team> <class>`
   *<team>***:** `red` | `blue`
   *<class>***:** `scout` | `soldier` | `pyro` | `demoman` | `heavyweapons` | `engineer` | `medic` | `sniper` | `spy`
   <sup>(e.g. `tf_bot_add blue heavyweapons`)</sup>
   To remove all bots: `tf_bot_kick all`

Here are some ways for your friend to connect. If one fails, try the next one.

- Join the game via Steam.
  <sup>In Steam Friends list press ▼ and Join Game.</sup>
- In console: `connect <ip>:27015`, where *<ip>* is your (server's) [IP address](http://duckduckgo.com/IP).
  <sup>(e.g. `connect 11.22.33.44:27015`)</sup>
- Try the same thing with your (server's) local IP address (find it in [Windows](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/windows-7/find-your-local-ip-address-windows-7-cmd/)/[Linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17012/how-to-find-your-ip-address-in-ubuntu/))

If nothing works, see the step 1 of server creation instruction.

Comment: Why is a public server (`sv_lan 0`) recommended for just playing over a LAN?

Comment: @NickT: There can be more problems with local connection than with internet one. You can try what suits best, but I don't know if your network is good, so I'm listing all options. Also, see **5.**

Comment: @BlaXpirit - Thanks - this looks like a great guide, including all the daft questions I was struggling with (how to open the console, etc).  It'll be the weekend till I can try again with my friend, so I'll post back after that, with how it goes :)

Comment: I've been able to test most of the answer, but haven't been able to test it with my friend yet, so can't say that it is fully tested and therefore accepted.  I've upvoted already and will accept this as soon as I've been able to confirm it

Comment: I confirm this process is working pretty fine on Linux 12.04 LTS. Just for reference. All the steps are clear and easy to perform. Thank you very much!

Comment: @BlaXpirit thank you very much for the answer. I wonder, is it possible to make some sort of script to automate this procedure, i.e. script that will execute those console commands. And then only execute this script, so whole process will consume less time?

Comment: `tf_bot_quota <n>` is an easy way to add a bunch of bots with auto-selected classes balanced across the teams.

Answer (score 7):

> The offline practice probably won't work as that looks like single player.

It actually runs an actual server on your machine that appears to be joinable to everyone in the world with the proper forwarding setup.

[image]

Comment: So if I start an offline game, they should be able to connect as we're on the same LAN?

Comment: @Durathor Yes, if the "IPv4 unspecified" kool aid Windows is serving me translates to "0.0.0.0" then the server will accept connections no matter what address they come from.

Comment: Hmm didn't immediately work - couldn't see it in the LAN tab on the 2nd player, and sending a game invite led to 'unable to connect to server <my public IP>.  I may need to do various port forwarding / translation for that.  As an alternative I tried doing 'create server'.  Which started a game my friend could join.  But I couldn't, just left looking at the 2fort bridge from on high.  And couldn't figure out how to add bots either.  I've been googling a fair bit about this and can't find a single good tutorial....

Comment: @Durathor What if he tried to connect to your private IP manually?

Comment: @badp thanks for the answer. The problem is, I don't know how to open port. I have tf2 installed on win 8 machine. In firewall settings tf2 is there and is checked. This should open port right? I'm trying to play co-op with bots on LAN.

Comment: @dhblah What IP are you using? It should start with eiter `192` or `10`; for example, `192.168.0.2`.

Comment: well, i tried connect to local IP (192.168.1.2) and it worked! thanks

Answer (score 4):

The TF2 wiki has [a page](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Bots) that lists the commands, AI and supported maps that bots can be used on. You do not need cheats to be on to use this type of bot. But puppet bots do.

So you start the server, join a team, say RED. Then type into the console `tf_bot_add blue`

Your friend joins and selects team RED too. Then type `tf_bot_add 13`

You will then have 8 people on both teams.

If you wish to change the difficulty of the bots, before adding the first bot, type `tf_bot_difficulty`.

Followed by the difficulty as a number: 0 = easy, 3 = expert, default 1 = normal.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do; it uses a few things from various answers above.

- Use the fastest LAN machine as your server, and figure out its IP address by typing `ipconfig` in a command prompt. This local IP address is probably something like `192.168.1.10`
- Make sure `hl2.exe` is set up as an application that can get through the server's firewall for your network (or if you're not using Windows Firewall, make sure port 27015 UDP traffic can get through)
- Start a server on the TF2 main menu of this machine
- In the server's TF2 console, use these commands to fill in bots on the team if there aren't 8 players per team:

  - `tf_bot_quota_mode fill`
  - `tf_bot_quota 16`
- Try to connect to this server from another machine on the LAN by typing `connect server_ip` in the TF2 console, replacing `server_ip` with the IP address of the server you identified above
- If you get a message that the password was not accepted, set the password to blank on the server's TF2 console with `sv_password ""`, and try connecting from the client again
- When the game starts, if the bots aren't moving, generate a "mesh" for them with these commands on the server's TF2 console:

  - `sv_cheats 1`
  - `nav_generate`